# Convert UTC time to local time zone in IE in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, localtime

I have a date time string in format ("2015-10-07 15:20:00 UTC") and i want to convert it to local time zone of client. i am using the following statements for this:

```
var UTC_Time = new Date ("2015-10-07 15:20:00 UTC");

var localTime = UTC_Time.toString();
```

in Google Chrome it works fine and return the converted time as 2015-10-07 20:20:00 PST which is fine. But in internet explorer (i am concerned with IE10) it is returning the same UTC date i.e. 2015-10-07 15:20:00. how can i get the converted time in IE. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of date operations, you may want to take a look at [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: There are not a lot of date operations but mostly the time conversion according to local timezone of client. Anyway, momentjs is a good suggestion but i am unable to get clients local timezone's standard name using momentjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you display a date in javascript, it converts it to the client time. Since you are specifying UTC in your date string, it will assume that it's a UTC date. There are a couple ways you can solve this.

If you just need a string, you can do `localTime = UTC_Time.toUTCString()`.

If you need a js Date object, you can create a new date object by getting the values from the previous object.

```
new Date(UTC_Time.getUTCFullYear(), UTC_Time.getUTCMonth(), 
    UTC_Time.getUTCDate(), UTC_Time.getUTCHours(), UTC_Time.getUTCMinutes(), 
    UTC_Time.getUTCSeconds(), UTC_Time.getUTCMilliseconds());
```

Or you can simply replace the UTC part of the string.

```
var dtStr = "2015-10-07 15:20:00 UTC";
dtStr = dtStr.replace(" UTC", "");
var localTime = new Date(dtStr);
```

Only use this option if you know your string will always be in the same format.